# Linking static fortran libraries with inter-dependencies

Tags: linker, dependencies, fortran, static-libraries

I am developing a Fortran program `prog1` and two Fortran  libraries, `lib1` and `lib2`. `prog1` depends on `lib1` and `lib2`, and `lib1` also depends on `lib2`. The directory structure might look like:

```
prog1
|- lib2
|- lib1
   |- lib2
```

In some cases, I would like `prog1` to use a different version of `lib2` than what `lib1` uses. However, if the static library `lib1.a` includes the object files from `lib2`, the linker gives me errors like

```
./lib1/lib1.a(lib2_module.o): In function `__lib2_module_MOD_function1':
./lib2/src/lib2_module.f90:12: multiple definition of `__lib2_module_MOD_function1'
./lib2/lib2.a(lib2_module.o):./lib2/src/lib2_module.f90:12: first defined here
```

In other words, the linker is confused since both libraries contain the same object file `lib2_module.o`, but with different versions.

So my question is: How can two Fortran libraries contain (and use) different versions of the same object files?

Comment: not an answer, but why would `prog1` need to depend on a different `lib1` version? If you can work around that, your problem might not exist.

Comment: In some cases, I might want to let `lib1` use the new version of `lib2`, but still let `prog1` use the old version, to avoid (or postpone) changing it. But using the same version would of course be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to do it by usage of static libraries. It is because from prog1 prespective, function1 from lib2's module is simple defined 2 times.
[On Wikipedia you can see that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)

> ...external functions and variables which are resolved in a caller at
>   compile-time and **copied** into a target application...

And you would probably not be suprised that this code would generate similar errors you see in your question:

**prog1.f90**

```
some code here... 

function funtion1(x) ...
  ...first version of function1 ...
end function

function funtion1(x) ...
  ...second version of function1 ...
end function

some code here...
```

One possibility would be to compile at least lib1 as shared library and make sure (compiler/platform dependent) that the symbols from lib2 are not exported from shared lib1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, wouldn't it be possible to make `lib2`'s functions in `lib1.a` have, say, a prefix that separates them from the ones that `prog1` uses directly from `lib2`?

Comment: @halvorlu I don't know any possibility